# How to identify which subView has been pressed in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a built a `UIView` class called `SetView`. In its initializer I create multiple `subviews` and later in `ViewController` I want to determine which `subView` has been pressed. in my `viewDidLoad` method I iterate through all the `subviews` add them to a class array of `UIView` called `mySubViews` and it my getIndex method, I am trying to retrieve the value which is always retrieved as nil. I suppose that it is my main view that is passed as a sender rather than particular `subviews` but I don't know how to pass specific `subviews` since #selector does not accept argument. I would appreciate any suggestions on how I could determine which `subview` was pressed to update features of a given `subview`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for view in setView.subviews {
        mySubViews.append(view)
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(getIndex(_:)))
        gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
}

@objc func getIndex(_ sender:UIView) {
    print(mySubViews.index(of: sender))
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add gesture to every of your subviews, add gesture in yous main view only. And from tap gesture sender you can get which view is tapped.

Comment: @iPeter what property of tap gesture should I use to retrieve which tap gesture sender was pressed? I have looked at the hash values and indeed they are different for different subviews clicked. However, they change with every compilation of the app so I cannot use them to identify specific subViews

Comment: Can you please just try `getIndex(_ sender:UIGestureRecognizer) { print(mySubViews.index(of: sender.view))`

Comment: Use only **One** tap gesture. and from `sender.view`,  you can get the view that is tapped.

Answer (score 3):

The sender should be the gesture recognizer. Then give your views a tag and set the same tag for your gesture recognizer. Then you can get the view with `viewWithTag`.

Or with your array it could be like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   var index = 0

   for view in setView.subviews {
       mySubViews.append(view)
       let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(getIndex(_:)))
       gestureRecognizer.tag = index
       gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
       view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

       index += 1
   }
}

@objc func getIndex(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print(mySubViews[sender.tag])
}
```

Comment: I believe you could do the same without tags and just use `sender.view`.

Comment: @MaticOblak You are right. I didn't want to post something I didn't tested to be sure it will work. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

The sender in your target method is a gesture recognizer. The fact that it is only interpreted as `UIView` will always return `nil` in your call.

Try the following:

```
@objc func getIndex(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    print(mySubViews.index(of: sender.view))
}
```

Still I would prefer you would use a single gesture recognizer on the super view. Then you can check the hit view by checking if the gesture recognizer was within the view bounds:

```
@objc func getIndex(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let allViewsAtGestureLocation = mySubViews.filter { $0.bounds.contains(sender.location(in: $0)) }
    let firstHitView = mySubViews.first(where: { $0.bounds.contains(sender.location(in: $0)) })
}
```

I assume you would need the second one. From it you can again find an index.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
for view in setView.subviews {
    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(getIndex(_:)))
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    mySubViews.addSubview(view)
}
```

Don't use append if you're trying to add it in, and add it after you assign the gesture.

Comment: It still gives nil after trying it.